# A problem with convertion from string to float in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion

I created that y list that equals ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', '451']
I tried to convert the type of y[3] into a float, but when I printed the type of y[3] it appeared to be a string somehow.

What is the problem?

```
 >>>x = "jan feb mar 451"
 ...y = x.split()
 ...float(y[3])
 ...type(y[3])
 str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign result of float convertion with e.g. `z = float(y[3])` 
or if you want to replace your string value with float you could do it with `y[3]=float(y[3])`.